# BigQuery + Angular + Firebase Functions results limited by oversize

Tags: angular, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the @ google-cloud/bigquery library with a Firebase feature, so I can bring data from BigQuery in Angular

**node library:** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/bigquery

My problem is that there are some fields that have a large number of bytes, and when I consult them, it does not bring them complete, it has a kind of limitation in this regard, I have already looked at the library documentation and have also been investigating the Google documentation and what I tried has not served, does anyone have any idea how I should proceed with this?

I do not find how to give more solution to this limitation, it would help me any kind of help

Comment: Are you getting any error message, or any indicator of whether the error is on the library or somewhere else?

Comment: @rsalinas I don't receive any error from the function, nor from Google, just BigQuery cuts the fields for the query's performance, but I don't know how to avoid this if I need all the data, no matter how big it is

Comment: If that's the case, you may be incurring into one of the Bigquery quotas mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), how big is the data you are retrieving?

Comment: varies between each record, there are some that reach 1,048,487 bytes or a little less

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to remove this limit?

Comment: you can open a support ticket to GCP for them to evaluate if they can increase the limit of the quota you are reaching, however, you wont be able to remove it, only increase is. Also, they may or may not approve your request, but it may be worth a shot

Comment: based on this using allowLargeResult: true, you should be able to bring the complete data, unless the quota and limit also applies to these requests https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/queryLegacyLargeResults.js